# Html contents with bootstrap theme and css are not loading in jenkins

Tags: html, css, jenkins, content-security-policy

In jenkins, i have archived *.html files which generated as test reports. html files are having bootstrap and other css components which are not loading.
Tried different combinations of configuring content security policy by reffering https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy but nothing worked. Even with empty string setting for argument hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP doesnt work. Not sure what is stopping to load the html files as expected.

**Note:** Test reports are generating in slave machine (Windows) which archived in master machine (linux) as below.

[htmlpublisher] Archiving at PROJECT level C:\scm\testing\NEW_SDI\Test\automation\SOAPUITestReportTool_Run1\output to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Automation_Testing/htmlreports/SoapUI_Reports

Also noticed that *.html files are expecting "./../ReportTemplate" directory where all the dependant files (e.g., css, js) are present.

Copied the ReportTemplate directory to the location "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Automation_Testing/htmlreports", "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Automation_Testing". But still html page is not coming as expected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TEST RUN | Dashboard</title>
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.4 -->
    <link href="../../ReportTemplate/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- FontAwesome 4.3.0 -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Ionicons 2.0.0 -->
    <link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link href="../../ReportTemplate/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
         folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
    <link href="../../ReportTemplate/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <link href="../../ReportTemplate/plugins/iCheck/flat/blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Morris chart -->
    <link href="../../ReportTemplate/plugins/morris/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- jvectormap -->
    <link href="../../ReportTemplate/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../../ReportTemplate/plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="js/custom/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
    <script src="../../ReportTemplate/js/custom/jquery-ui-custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../ReportTemplate/js/custom/jquery.layout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../ReportTemplate/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="../../ReportTemplate/js/custom/ui.multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../ReportTemplate/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="../../ReportTemplate/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- FLOT RESIZE PLUGIN - allows the chart to redraw when the window is resized -->
    <script src="../../ReportTemplate/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.resize.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- FLOT PIE PLUGIN - also used to draw donut charts -->
    <script src="../../ReportTemplate/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.pie.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- FLOT CATEGORIES PLUGIN - Used to draw bar charts -->
    <script src="../../ReportTemplate/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.categories.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- bootstrap wysihtml5 - text editor -->
    <link href="../../ReportTemplate/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via  -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../../ReportTemplate/css/jquery-ui-custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../../ReportTemplate/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../../ReportTemplate/css/ui.multiselect.css" />

    <!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Resolve conflict in jQuery UI tooltip with Bootstrap tooltip -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
    </script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.2 JS -->
    <script src="../../ReportTemplate/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Morris.js charts -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../ReportTemplate/plugins/morris/morris.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Sparkline -->
    <script src="../../ReportTemplate/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- jvectormap -->
    <script src="../../ReportTemplate/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../ReportTemplate/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- jQuery Knob Chart -->
    <script src="../../ReportTemplate/plugins/knob/jquery.knob.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- daterangepicker -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap WYSIHTML5 -->
    <script src="../../ReportTemplate/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Slimscroll -->
    <script src="../../ReportTemplate/plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- FastClick -->
    <script src="../../ReportTemplate/plugins/fastclick/fastclick.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script src="../../ReportTemplate/dist/js/app.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE dashboard demo (This is only for demo purposes) -->
    <script src="../../ReportTemplate/dist/js/pages/dashboard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
    <script src="../../ReportTemplate/dist/js/demo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  </head>
  <body class="skin-blue sidebar-mini">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <header class="main-header">
        <!-- Logo -->
        <a href="http:\\google.com" class="logo">
          <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->

          <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
          <span class="logo-lg"><img src="../../ReportTemplate/css/images/test-logo.png" width="150" height="50" alt="" title="" /></span>

        </a>
        <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
          <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
          <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          </a>        
          <h4 align="center"><font color="#FFFFFF"><b>SDI - One Touch Automation Test Report</b></font></h4>
          </nav>
      </header>
      <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
      <aside class="main-sidebar">
        <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
        <section class="sidebar">
          <!-- Sidebar user panel -->
          <div class="user-panel">
            <div class="pull-left image">
            </div>
            <div class="pull-left info">
              <p></p>
              <a href="#"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- search form -->
          <form action="#" method="get" class="sidebar-form">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" name="search" id="search-btn" class="btn btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
              </span>
            </div>
          </form>
          <!-- /.search form -->
          <!-- sidebar menu: : style can be found in sidebar.less -->
          <ul class="sidebar-menu">
            <li class="header">Menu</li>
            <li class="active treeview">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Test Report</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
              </a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </section>
        <!-- /.sidebar -->
      </aside>

      <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <section class="content-header">
          <h1>SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1 - Thu Dec 01 04:55:21 MST 2016</h1>

          <!--ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
            <li class="active">Dashboard</li>
          </ol-->
        </section>

        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">
          <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
              <!-- small box -->
              <div class="small-box bg-green">
                <div class="inner">
                  <h3>74.39 %</h3>
                  <h5>Count: 122</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                  <!--i class="ion ion-bag"></i-->
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="small-box-footer"><b>Passed</b></a>
              </div>
            </div><!-- ./col -->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
              <!-- small box -->
              <div class="small-box bg-red">
                <div class="inner">
                  <h3>25.61 %</h3>
                  <h5>Count: 42</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                  <!--i class="ion ion-stats-bars"></i-->
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="small-box-footer"><b>Failed</b></a>
              </div>
            </div><!-- ./col -->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
              <!-- small box -->
              <div class="small-box bg-yellow">
                <div class="inner">
                  <h3>0%</h3>
                  <h5>Count: 0</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                  <!--i class="ion ion-person-add"></i-->
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="small-box-footer"><b>Cancelled</b></a>
              </div>
            </div><!-- ./col -->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
              <!-- small box -->
              <div class="small-box bg-aqua">
                <div class="inner">
                  <h3>0%</h3>
                  <h5>Count: 0</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                  <!--i class="ion ion-pie-graph"></i-->
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="small-box-footer"><b>Unknown</b></a>
              </div>
            </div><!-- ./col -->
          </div><!-- /.row -->
          <!-- Main row -->

          <div class="row">
            <!-- Left col -->

        <section class="col-lg-12 connectedSortable">
              <!-- Custom tabs (Charts with tabs)-->
              <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
                <!-- Tabs within a box -->
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-right">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#testresult-chart" data-toggle="tab">Chart</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#testresult-table" data-toggle="tab">Table</a></li>
                  <li class="pull-left header"><i class="fa fa-table"></i> Test Suite Summary</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content no-padding">
                  <!-- Morris chart - Sales -->
                  <div class="chart tab-pane active" id="testresult-chart" style="position: relative; height: 600px;"></div>
                  <div class="chart tab-pane" id="testresult-table" style="position: relative; height: 600px;">
                    <table id="44remote3"></table>
                    <div id="p44remote3"></div>
                    <div id="plist48"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div><!-- /.nav-tabs-custom -->

            </section><!-- /.Left col -->
            <!-- right col (We are only adding the ID to make the widgets sortable)-->
            <!--section class="col-lg-5 connectedSortable"-->
            <!--/section--><!-- right col -->

          </div><!-- /.row (main row) -->

        </section><!-- /.content -->
      </div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->
      <footer class="main-footer">
        <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
        <br/>
        </div>
        <br/>
      </footer>

    </div><!-- ./wrapper -->

<!-- table report -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
    $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var reportTableData=[{Id:"1",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB Look UP",TestCase:"MIB - LOOKUP valid",TestStep:"MIB Lookup valid",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"851",ExecutedAt:"Thu Dec 01 04:55:21 MST 2016",Size:"614",Logs:"MIB Lookup valid.txt"},{Id:"2",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB Look UP",TestCase:"MIB - LOOKUP valid",TestStep:"invalid DER and Valid DDN",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"268",ExecutedAt:"Thu Dec 01 04:55:21 MST 2016",Size:"335",Logs:"invalid DER and Valid DDN.txt"},{Id:"3",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB Look UP",TestCase:"MIB - LOOKUP valid",TestStep:"valid DDV and invalid DER",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"166",ExecutedAt:"Thu Dec 01 04:55:22 MST 2016",Size:"606",Logs:"valid DDV and invalid DER.txt"},{Id:"4",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB Look UP",TestCase:"MIB - LOOKUP valid",TestStep:"valid DER and invalid DDN",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"264",ExecutedAt:"Thu Dec 01 04:55:22 MST 2016",Size:"657",Logs:"valid DER and invalid DDN.txt"},{Id:"5",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB Look UP",TestCase:"MIB - LOOKUP valid",TestStep:"Valid DER and invalid DDV",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"201",ExecutedAt:"Thu Dec 01 04:55:22 MST 2016",Size:"604",Logs:"Valid DER and invalid DDV.txt"},{Id:"6",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB Look UP",TestCase:"DER only",TestStep:"DER ONLY",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"1947",ExecutedAt:"Thu Dec 01 04:55:22 MST 2016",Size:"612",Logs:"DER ONLY.txt"},{Id:"7",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB Look UP",TestCase:"DER only",TestStep:"invald DER",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"141",ExecutedAt:"Thu Dec 01 04:55:24 MST 2016",Size:"335",Logs:"invald DER.txt"},{Id:"8",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB Look UP",TestCase:"DER only",TestStep:"invalid DER Special Character",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"206",ExecutedAt:"Thu Dec 01 04:55:24 MST 2016",Size:"643",Logs:"invalid DER Special Character.txt"},{Id:"9",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB Look UP",TestCase:"DER only",TestStep:"long DER",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"154",ExecutedAt:"Thu Dec 01 04:55:25 MST 2016",Size:"719",Logs:"long DER.txt"},{Id:"10",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB Look UP",TestCase:"DDN only",TestStep:"DDN only",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"248",ExecutedAt:"Thu Dec 01 04:55:25 MST 2016",Size:"616",Logs:"DDN only.txt"},{Id:"11",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB Look UP",TestCase:"DDN only",TestStep:"valid DDN 2",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"155",ExecutedAt:"Thu Dec 01 04:55:25 MST 2016",Size:"634",Logs:"valid DDN 2.txt"},{Id:"12",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB Look UP",TestCase:"DDN only",TestStep:"Invalid DDN",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"227",ExecutedAt:"Thu Dec 01 04:55:25 MST 2016",Size:"335",Logs:"Invalid DDN.txt"},{Id:"13",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB Look UP",TestCase:"DDN only",TestStep:"long DDN Value",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"160",ExecutedAt:"Thu Dec 01 04:55:26 MST 2016",Size:"335",Logs:"long DDN Value.txt"},{Id:"14",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB Look UP",TestCase:"DDV in all input fields",TestStep:"DDV in all input fields",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"201",ExecutedAt:"Thu Dec 01 04:55:26 MST 2016",Size:"603",Logs:"DDV in all input fields.txt"},{Id:"15",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB Look UP",TestCase:"invalid XML schema",TestStep:"invalid XML Schema",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"125",ExecutedAt:"Thu Dec 01 04:55:26 MST 2016",Size:"676",Logs:"invalid XML Schema.txt"},{Id:"16",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB Look UP",TestCase:"Relative DDN",TestStep:"valid Relative DDN Upper Case",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"206",ExecutedAt:"Thu Dec 01 04:55:26 MST 2016",Size:"606",Logs:"valid Relative DDN Upper Case.txt"},{Id:"17",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB Look UP",TestCase:"Relative DDN",TestStep:"Valid DDN lower Case",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"143",ExecutedAt:"Thu Dec 01 04:55:26 MST 2016",Size:"606",Logs:"Valid DDN lower Case.txt"},{Id:"18",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB Look UP",TestCase:"Relative DDN",TestStep:"combination of Upper and lower case Relative DDN",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"197",ExecutedAt:"Thu Dec 01 04:55:26 MST 2016",Size:"606",Logs:"combination of Upper and lower case Relative DDN.txt"},{Id:"19",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB Look UP",TestCase:"Relative DDN",TestStep:"invalid Relative DDN Upper Case",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"293",ExecutedAt:"Thu Dec 01 04:55:27 MST 2016",Size:"335",Logs:"invalid Relative DDN Upper Case.txt"},{Id:"20",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB Look UP",TestCase:"Relative DDN",TestStep:"in Valid DDN lower Case",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"223",ExecutedAt:"Thu Dec 01 04:55:27 MST 2016",Size:"335",Logs:"in Valid DDN lower Case.txt"},{Id:"21",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB Look UP",TestCase:"Relative DDN",TestStep:"in valid combination of Upper and lower case Relative DDN",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"222",ExecutedAt:"Thu Dec 01 04:55:27 MST 2016",Size:"335",Logs:"in valid combination of Upper and lower case Relative DDN.txt"},{Id:"22",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB Look UP",TestCase:"Relative DDN",TestStep:"Valid DER Relative",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"203",ExecutedAt:"Thu Dec 01 04:55:27 MST 2016",Size:"465",Logs:"Valid DER Relative.txt"},{Id:"23",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB Look UP",TestCase:"3 in 1 but DDV is invalid",TestStep:"DDV invalid",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"147",ExecutedAt:"Thu Dec 01 04:55:28 MST 2016",Size:"604",Logs:"DDV invalid.txt"},{Id:"24",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB Look UP",TestCase:"3 in 1 DDN is invalid",TestStep:"DDN invalid",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"193",ExecutedAt:"Thu Dec 01 04:55:28 MST 2016",Size:"635",Logs:"DDN invalid.txt"},{Id:"25",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB GET CHILDREN",TestCase:"MIB GC valid DDN",TestStep:"MIB GC valid demoi",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"324",ExecutedAt:"Thu Dec 01 04:55:28 MST 2016",Size:"10681",Logs:"MIB GC valid demoi.txt"},{Id:"26",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB GET CHILDREN",TestCase:"MIB GC valid DDN",TestStep:"MIB GC valid1",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"1281",ExecutedAt:"Thu Dec 01 04:55:28 MST 2016",Size:"1356360",Logs:"MIB GC valid1.txt"},{Id:"27",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB GET CHILDREN",TestCase:"MIB GC valid DDN",TestStep:"GC Valid 2",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"135",ExecutedAt:"Thu Dec 01 04:55:30 MST 2016",Size:"3025",Logs:"GC Valid 2.txt"},{Id:"28",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB GET CHILDREN",TestCase:"MIB GC Invalid DDN",TestStep:"invalid DDN GC",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"252",ExecutedAt:"Thu Dec 01 04:55:30 MST 2016",Size:"351",Logs:"invalid DDN GC.txt"},{Id:"29",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB GET CHILDREN",TestCase:"MIB GC Invalid DDN",TestStep:"nvalid DDN GC 2",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"248",ExecutedAt:"Thu Dec 01 04:55:30 MST 2016",Size:"351",Logs:"nvalid DDN GC 2.txt"},{Id:"30",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB GET CHILDREN",TestCase:"ALL 3 in one request(Different)",TestStep:"3 in 1 Different DDV,DDN and DER",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"203",ExecutedAt:"Thu Dec 01 04:55:30 MST 2016",Size:"647",Logs:"3 in 1 Different DDV,DDN and DER.txt"},{Id:"31",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB GET CHILDREN",TestCase:"ALL 3 in one request(Different)",TestStep:"3 in 1 same  DDV,DDN and DER",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"114",ExecutedAt:"Thu Dec 01 04:55:31 MST 2016",Size:"647",Logs:"3 in 1 same  DDV,DDN and DER.txt"},{Id:"32",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB GET CHILDREN",TestCase:"Relative DDN",TestStep:"Relative DDN Valid",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"214",ExecutedAt:"Thu Dec 01 04:55:31 MST 2016",Size:"1484",Logs:"Relative DDN Valid.txt"},{Id:"33",Project:"SDI REGRESSION PRE PROD_1",TestSuite:"MIB GET CHILDREN",TestCase:"Relative DDN",TestStep:"Relative DDN invalid",TestStatus:"OK",Passed:"1",Failed:"0",TimeTaken:"124",ExecutedAt:"Thu 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you see any warnings or errors in the browser console?

Comment: @AnandBhat No. dont see any warnings or errors in any browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox).